# How does Perl handle sessions differently from PHP?

Tags: perl, session

I'm trying to clone a commercial Student Management System which was written in Perl. I want to use PHP, as I have no experience in Perl.
I am now trying to set up the login system, which should be (has to be?) done with PHPSESSID's, right? Now, in PHP I could transmit the Session ID via GET, POST, and COOKIE.

The Perl website doesn't add parameters to the URL (GET) and does not save cookies on my computer (COOKIE). There is also no form which could contain a hidden field (which would be POST in PHP, right?)

Can someone tell me how Perl remembers the logged in user there?

Comment: Perhaps it uses HTTP Authentication instead, see if your client is sending an Authorization header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl takes a much more "toolkit"-based approach to building web applications than PHP does, because Perl was not designed specifically for web work.  So it doesn't have any built-in way of doing web app session management; rather, there are many modules on CPAN which implement session management in many different ways.

If you were to identify the Student Management System in question and provide a URL, we might be able to look at it from the outside and identify what it's doing, but, really, I question whether you actually need to use the same session management system as the existing app unless you want to implement single-sign-on between the original version and your clone[1].  Concentrate on cloning the user-visible interface and functionality rather than the implementation details behind it.

[1]  ...which would be futile anyhow unless you're also planning to tap into its session database on the back end, since neither one will recognize the other's session ids if they don't share that data.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for the 'best' secure solution in PHP and tried to copy the original's solution. But you are probably right -- I should restrict the copying to the user interface and build the interior myself.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, there are OTHER, non-standard ways to store/transmit session information than the 3 methods you listed (although I **seriously doubt** any of them are used in your SMS). Among them:

- Sending the cookie data as part of the DOM (e.g. in HTML) and having on-page JavaScript access it from DOM
- Or, just store the cookied data as JavaScript's data in the first place.
- AJAX calls. E.g. the session-enabled logic is all handled in AJAX URLs and not the main URLs. Yes, I know that's completely screwy. But doable.
- Don't store the cookie in main cookie database (so you can't find it using standard cookie viewing methods). For details on how that's done, please google "evercookie" for a VERY cool method of persistently storing cookie info by utilizing up to 10 redundant storage options - one good intro is http://blog.depthsecurity.com/2010/09/super-persistent-cookies-evercookie.html

All that said, I completely agree with Dave's answer - just use PHP's best practices mechanism to implement the functionality instead of cloning possibly-perl-specific and possibly-weird implementation in the webapp.